# Set the hostname/computer name for macOS

Tags: macos, network

I have a local network at home. This network contains 5 laptops. One of the laptops is a Mac with macOS 10.8 on it. The other has a Linux installed, all others run Windows.

When trying to open my router and check "Connected devices", under the IP address of this Mac I see following:

Host Name - some IPV6 address

What I'd rather prefer to see is some meaningful name so that I can use that in the `/etc/hosts` file in Linux laptop. And also I'd like to check the computer name so that the /etc/hosts line was proper.

Answer (score 188):

[Setting the Mac hostname or computer name from the terminal](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/smoke/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Setting-the-Mac-hostname-or-computer-name-from-the-terminal.html)

> 1. Open a terminal.
> 2. Type the following command to change the **primary hostname** of your Mac:
>      This is your fully qualified hostname, for example myMac.domain.com
>
>    ```
>    sudo scutil --set HostName <new host name>
>    ```
> 3. Type the following command to change the **Bonjour hostname** of your Mac:
>      This is the name usable on the local network, for example myMac.local.
>
>    ```
>    sudo scutil --set LocalHostName <new host name>
>    ```
> 4. If you also want to change the **computer name**, type the following command:
>      This is the user-friendly computer name you see in Finder, for example myMac.
>
>    ```
>    sudo scutil --set ComputerName <new name>
>    ```
> 5. Flush the DNS cache by typing:
>
>    ```
>    dscacheutil -flushcache
>    ```
> 6. Restart your Mac.

Comment: after doing this I still see the IPv6 address in the router. Any idea? And what would be the line in the /etc/hosts file on Linux if I set the hostnames to MyMac?

Comment: Always attribute quoted content with an appropriate source link and use quote formatting for quoted content. I've added a potential source link but please [edit] if this is incorrect.

Comment: `scutil --get HostName` shows the current value of HostName.

Comment: Should we done all steps?

Comment: `hostname` also shows the current value of HostName, right? Or is there some difference between this and `scutil --get HostName`?

Comment: `sudo hostname <new-host-name>` also sets hostname that can be used from terminal. It would be nice to see what is the difference and relations between these internal *hostnames* in MacOS and standard \*nix hostnames (as @scrpy asked). Additionally, `System Preferences -> Sharing` is another place to change some hostname, so again, what is the diff to previous hostname settings?

Answer (score 22):

You can set the computer name in System Preferences → Sharing.

[image]

Comment: @ggarside, I still see an IPv6 as a computer name inside the router. It is a Comcast modem/router one. Any idea?

Comment: this doesn't seem to change the hostname returned by the `hostname` command in terminal

Comment: @Woodstock it does seem to be linked somehow, but does not get updated immediately

Comment: @grg Do you know what this difference is between this and the NetBIOS Name in the Network -> Advanced section of Preferences?

Answer (score 4):

## You need to set the hostname in two places

1. System Settings -> General -> About -> Name
2. In a terminal, `sudo scutil --set HostName <new host name>`

You can verify the hostname is correctly updated by doing:

```
scutil --get HostName 
scutil --get LocalHostName 
scutil --get ComputerName
```

Then, `dscacheutil -flushcache` and restart your mac.

Comment: Thanks, works for me on Sonoma 14.0.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS 13, computer name can be changed from:

System Settings -> General -> About -> Name

This changes the computer name displayed in Terminal, Sharing, Finder, etc. No system restart required.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. Used to work in the past, now I see "mac.local" and does not propagate the change.¨

Comment: @lzap For the benefit of future readers of this question, in which macOS version did this not work? It worked fine for me on macOS 13.

Comment: I am on 13.4. The path via Settings did not work for me, "scutil" utility did.

For the record, I am interested in changing the UNIX hostname variable, not the thing that is displayed somewhere in Apple UI.

Comment: This approach works, but you may need a system restart to see the effect.

Answer (score -1):

On your Mac, choose Apple menu > System Settings, click General in the sidebar, then click Sharing on the right. ...
Click Edit in the “Local hostname” section at the bottom of the window, then enter a new local hostname.
If needed, turn on the “Use dynamic global hostname” option.

Comment: Was it ChatGPT or Bing Chat that got your this answer which was sourced from [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-a-dynamic-global-hostname-on-mac-mh27452/mac)?This answer also doesn't offer anything new that hasn't already been posted by others.