# Can we view or edit HostName value via macOS desktop UI?

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra, sharing, system-settings

Here are two instances where I found that setting the computer name via System Preferences > Sharing > Computer Name does not really set the `HostName` attribute.

The macOS version is macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6 in both instances below.

#### Instance 1

I got a brand new MacBook Pro which had the following settings under System Preferences > Sharing.

- Computer Name: Lone's MacBook Pro
- Local Hostname: Lones-MacBook-Pro.local

The `scutil` and `hostname` output looked like this:

```
$ scutil --get ComputerName
Lone's MacBook Pro
$ scutil --get LocalHostName
Lones-MacBook-Pro
$ scutil --get HostName
HostName: not set
$ hostname
Lones-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Then I went to System Preferences > Sharing and set the Computer Name to `luke`. Now the output looked like this:

```
$ scutil --get ComputerName
luke
$ scutil --get LocalHostName
luke
$ scutil --get HostName
HostName: not set
$ hostname
luke.local
```

The `HostName` attribute is not set!

#### Instance 2

I was working on a friend's MacBook Pro who had some other `HostName` already set (perhaps someone else had configured it for him). He had the following settings under System Preferences > Sharing.

- Computer Name: mmod
- Local Hostname: mmod.local

The CLI output looked like this:

```
$ scutil --get ComputerName
mmod
$ scutil --get LocalHostName
mmod
$ scutil --get HostName
mmod
$ hostname
mmod
```

Now I went to System Preferences > Sharing and set Computer Name to `luke`. The output now is:

```
$ scutil --get ComputerName
luke
$ scutil --get LocalHostName
luke
$ scutil --get HostName
mmod
$ hostname
mmod
```

Again, `HostName` remains unaffected.

#### Question

I know that I can set the `HostName` attribute with the `scutil --set HostName luke` command.

My question is: Is there a macOS desktop UI element where I can view or edit this `HostName` attribute without having to run CLI commands?

Answer (score 3):

**There's no place in the GUI to change it, because it's typically set by an *external* source.**

[Your `hostname` is determined by the following](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303411/119271) (in order):

- name supplied by DHCP/BOOTP server
- name returned by a reverse DNS lookup
- the localhost name (what was used to set `LocalHostName` value)
- name acutal name `localhost`

Most routers now have the ability to "register" the DHCP lease in the DNS resolver cache.  So, what's happening is this...

At some point, your Mac didn't exist as a DHCP mapping or DNS entry on your router.  When it connected, it sent a request which included it's preferred hostname along with a request for an address.  That preferred hostname defaulted to your `LocalHostName` as the first two conditions would have returned nothing.  When you got the address, it "registered" that hostname with an IP.

Now, you want to change the name, but it keeps coming back to the original host - this is because the router now "knows" your machine has having that name and will overwrite it per DNS (which takes priority).

#### TL;DR

That name is coming from your DHCP Server and/or DNS chache.  If you want to clear that out and set a new one, you'll have to do it at the router.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but according to this articled titled: [How to Change Your Computer Name on Mac OS X](https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-change-your-computer-name-on-mac-os-x/) you can change the hostname under the System Preferences.

*Under the Sharing Menu*

[image: ss1]

*You can click the Edit button and change the hostname*

[image: ss2]

After make the above change, you'll want to make sure and restart the terminal so that the above change gets picked up.

**NOTE:** The above should have the same effect as doing this:

In addition to your method of using the CLI:

```
$ sudo scutil --set HostName [NewHostNameHere]
```

#### References

- [Set the hostname/computer name for macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287760/set-the-hostname-computer-name-for-macos)

Comment: In my question, I have mentioned that I have tried exactly what you describe and it does not change the `HostName` value. I have also included `scutil --set HostName luke` as a possible solution in my question. Do you have an answer to the actual question I ask, i.e., Can we view or edit HostName value via macOS desktop UI?

Comment: @LoneLearner - Missed that you did these steps, there's one additional detail that seems to make the difference.. Did you restart the terminal afterwards?

Comment: @LoneLearner - others are reporting in this Q&A as well - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal. There's a detail that if you override using the `scutil --set <cmds>` may disable the Sharing dialog's settings from getting picked up. You may need to remove/delete them so that it'll be picked up from the GUI.

Comment: Also note that DNS host names cannot contain spaces

Comment: @slm Yes, the results in my questions are obtained after restarting the terminal. So it seems like the `HostName` value can only be set via `scutil --set` and there is no way to view or edit it via the desktop GUI?

Comment: @LoneLearner that doesn't seem consistent w/ the research that I've done thus far. There are instances where ppl are changing it via the GUI and it's being picked up in the terminal which is consistent w/ what you're looking for.

Comment: @LoneLearner - I would suggest clearing out the settings via the CLI by setting things to nothing, `''`, and then going through the steps again using just the GUI.