# Environment Variable $HOST Changes to My LAN IP Automatically

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

I'm using `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` on macOS Monterey 12.6, and I found that sometimes the hostname changes to `192` automatically. After having a check, I found sometimes environment variable `$HOST` becomes my LAN IP, which starts with `192` automatically.

How can I fix that variable to a desired value? Do I need to set it in cli or gui? Is there any possible reason that it changes to my LAN IP?

Comment: I think I'd look to see what oh-my-zsh might be doing.  `$HOST` isn't a variable macOS sets, it's something `zsh` sets.

Comment: I found [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287760/set-the-hostname-computer-name-for-macos) about setting hostname by `scutil`. And on my computer, `scutil --get HostName` gives unset. However, it seems there's no way to revert it after `scutil --set HostName <something>`, and the reason `$HOST` variable changes is still unknown, so I don't want to solve the problem in this way.

Comment: I tried `unset HOST`and started a new terminal, an `echo $HOST` gives the same value as `scutil --get LocalHostName`. It seems that the problem is temporarily fixed, but I still don't know why `$HOST` changed to my LAN IP.